# Multiple colliders causes cloth simulation to freak out

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation, collision

I've got a simulation dropping a cloth onto a couple of mesh objects. When I test it with just 1 object, it seems mostly stable.

When I involve a second object/mesh that's touching the first, it starts to jump, buck, stutter around. On a lot of settings it crumples into insane balls and crushes itself. This largely does not happen with the first object.

I've tried EVERYTHING under the sun I can think of. Tweaking all sorts of cloth properties, cloth quality sim level, different tweaks to the colliders as well... no matter what I do, if the cloth and those ears touch, there's an unstoppable freakout. Definitely at my wit's end with this. Please let me know if you have any theories.

[image]

Comment: if i run your blend file simulation, it works fine. did you delete/inactivate the second object? what is your second object?

Comment: The ears object. I did yes, sorry about that.

Comment: The main body and the ears are the two colliders (Or should be), the poncho is the cloth object.